# what does non integer sided polygon mean?

Tags: trigonometry

i've calculated formula for n sided regular polygon about ratio of the radius and perimeter.

$K=2n\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})$

$n$ stands for number of sides

so for any n sided regular polygon its true that

$Perimeter=K*Radius$

but i've noticed that the formula is periodic from -1 to 1
i know it might not even make any sense but what does this non integer sides actually mean but look visually, or even less than 1 sided polygon

Comment: What's periodic? $x\mapsto 2x\sin\frac\pi x$ certainly isn't.

Comment: As for the rest, even $n\mapsto n$ is the somehow natural restiction of the map $x\mapsto x$ from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$ (or, similarly, $x(x-3)/2$ for the number of diagonals in a convex polygon). Why does $2x\sin\frac\pi x$ attract your interest, specifically?

Comment: i dont know why specifically this formula. its just what i was working on and it caught my interest. i just cant imagine its defined by the formula but how does it look like, what does it actually mean? is it a complex figure? for example 2d figure with z axes of complex part? or is my vision of it entirely wrong?

Comment: What you are doing is a fairly common fallacy. You obtained this formula for positive integers from geometry. You note that the formula itself is sensible for non-integers, so you assume that there must also be some geometric interpretation for non-integers. It is quite often the case that formulas derived from particular cases also have meaning more generally, so your assumption is not without merit. However "quite often the case" falls far short of "always the case". There are many places where extending the formula to non-integer values completely divorces it from geometry.

Answer (score 2):

@LongToeBoy It's a good question and I too have pondered upon such questions related to extending math formulae derived in the context of natural numbers to non-integers (n-Factorial for instance). One of the ways to do this via fractional polygons is detailed here:  https://chalkdustmagazine.com/blog/fractional-polygons/

The basic gist of the idea explained above is to use the concept of external angles of a regular n-gon.  Using the well known formula for internal angle
of n-gon, you can derive the external angle as depicted in the following image

[image]

We can then look at drawing the n-gon as follows using the external angle.
[image]

The concept can be extended for non-integer sides. For instance , for n = 2.5, the external angles would 360/2.5 = 144 degree.

Drawing this diagram using the above process turns out to be the following star diagram. (pardon the hand drawing, I don't have the patience to animate it)

[image]

Comment: thank you for the animations and effort you put into this comment, but i still have some questions. why does the star have five points specifically? couldnt it have lets say 17 sides with the same 144° external angles? would some other number of sides (instead of 2.5) for example 4.8 change number of points?

Comment: @LongToeBoy , To answer your second query first:  yes. the star does not need to have 5 points and it can change based on the angle we select. The link I gave has a sample with 11 points and 7 points star as well.  Coming back to the first query "Couldnt it have 17 sides with same 144°  extrenal angle" . I dont have a rigorous proof but probably it wont since you can see that the star is enclosing a regular polygon in the center and based on the construction we have chosen, the number of points will be fixed based on the number of angles which will be dtermined by the contained polygon.